# recursive application of C++20 range adaptor causes a compile time infinite loop

Tags: c++, stl, c++20, std-ranges

The ranges library in C++20 supports the expression

```
auto view = r | std::views::drop(n);
```

to remove the first `n` elements of a range `r` with the range adaptor `drop`.

However if I recursively drop elements from a range, the compiler enters an infinite loop.

---

Minimal working example: (takes infinite time to compile in GCC 10)

```
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template<ranges::range T>
void printCombinations(T values) {
    if(values.empty())
        return;

    auto tail = values | views::drop(1);

    for(auto val : tail)
        cout << values.front() << " " << val << endl;

    printCombinations(tail);
}

int main() {
    auto range1 = array<int, 4> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    printCombinations(range1);
    cout << endl;

    string range2 = "abc";
    printCombinations(range2);
    cout << endl;
}
```

expected output:

```
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 3
2 4
3 4

a b
a c
b c
```

Why does this take infinite time to compile and how should I resolve the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's take a look at the `string` case (just because that type is shorter) and manually examine the call stack.

`printCombinations(range2)` calls `printCombinations<string>`. The function recursively calls itself with `tail`. What's the type of `tail`? That's `drop_view<ref_view<string>>`. So we call `printCombinations<drop_view<ref_view<string>>>`. Straightforward so far.

Now, we again recursively call ourselves with `tail`. What's the type of `tail` *now*? Well, we just wrap. It's `drop_view<drop_view<ref_view<string>>>`. And then we recurse again with `drop_view<drop_view<drop_view<ref_view<string>>>>`. And then we recurse again with `drop_view<drop_view<drop_view<drop_view<ref_view<string>>>>>`. And so forth, infinitely, until the compiler explodes.

Can we fix this by maintaining the same algorithm? Actually, yes. [P1739](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1739r4.html) was about reducing this kind of template instantiation bloat (although it didn't have an example as amusing as this one). And so `drop_view` has a few [special cases](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.drop#overview-2) for views that it recognizes and won't rewrap. 
The type of `"hello"sv | views::drop(1)` is still `string_view`, not `drop_view<string_view>`. So `printCombinations(string_view(range2))` should only generate a single template instantiation.

But it looks like libstdc++ doesn't implement this feature yet. So you can either implement it manually (but only trafficking in, say, [`subrange`](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.subrange)) or abandon the recursive approach here.

Comment: Is there a way to implement the `values.empty()` base case using a more specific template? Something like `template<range::empty_range T> void printCombination(T values) {}`? If such a template is allowed it could terminate the recursion.

Comment: @ProgrammierPatrick The size of these ranges is a runtime property, so no.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Although this is very old question, but I came across this annoying bug/(or maybe feature) today, and this is how I solved it without much change to the original code.

```cpp
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <span>   /////// <------ added this

using namespace std;

template<ranges::range T>
void printCombinations(T values_) {  // <--- Changed values to values_
    auto values = std::span(values_);  // <--- defined values here
    if(values.empty())
        return;

    auto tail = values | views::drop(1);

    for(auto val : tail)
        cout << values.front() << " " << val << endl;

    printCombinations(tail);
}

int main() {
    auto range1 = array<int, 4> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    printCombinations(range1);
    cout << endl;

    string range2 = "abc";
    printCombinations(range2);
    cout << endl;
}
```

By creating span, we make the `typename` of the variable simply `span` instead of deeply nested `typename`s as shown in the accepted answer.

You can check it [here on goldbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/jeEKvs97d) that it works exactly as expected.

UPDATE:
You can replace the use of `std::span` with `std::ranges::subrange` and it will cover even more cases. For example, `std::span` does not work with `std::ranges::views::reverse`.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `std::ranges::subrange`, this seems to be the best solution for the problem.
I haven't used ranges since. Would you keep the general `template <range T> void printCombinations(T values)`, or would is make more sense to expose the `subrange` directly as the parameter as `template <class T> void printCombinations(subrange<T> values)`?

Comment: @ProgrammierPatrick I'm sorry I don't know it myself. Similar to you, I also do not have much experience of using ranges.